# Can I run CakePHP on Google App Engine PHP runtime?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cakephp

Has anyone tried to do this?

Cake needs a tmp folder with writable permissions so I guess it isn't possible. Or is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: I don't think so. That question is about running PHP with quercus using the Java runtime. I'm talking about the new PHP runtime lauched yesterday.

Comment: Interesting. Well, if you can't create a writable tmp folder I would not do this.

Comment: even though this got marked as a dupe it's probably not - as the accepted answer on the other question was from a time before GAE natively supported PHP. What does cakePHP use the /tmp folder for?

Comment: @Stuart Langley: I can't say for Cake, but PHP "normally" uses tmp for Session files and File-Uploads. I wondered about how you manage file-uploads as well, so is there some tmp that actually exists or how is that done? All into the cloud storage buckets by default?

Comment: @harke: Everything into Cloud Storage - look at CloudStorageUtil::createUploadUrl to how to make the action to point your form to - from there it should all flow as normal. For sessions, by default we store them in memcache, which is fine for some apps but if you want something more resilliant then into Cloud SQL they should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to specify an alternate location for the /tmp directory CakePHP writes to? If so, you might want to try specifying to a Cloud Storage bucket. eg. gs://my-cake-bucket/tmp/

More info:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/overview

Comment: Cloudstorage is writable, but not updatedatable.  I don't know what CakePHP whats to write, but you can't truncate, or modify what you have written.

Comment: You can overwrite, just not append to an existing object.